# Shiny Rmarkdown html download

Tags: r, shiny, r-markdown, flexdashboard

In my `Rmarkdownfile` I want to download my `.rmd` as a `html` file but I get the following error.

> Warning: Error in file. Cannot open the connection.

I think it's because of the external file included by source(...), but I don't know why. In the external file I make a connection to a db.

````
---
output: 
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
    orientation: columns
    vertical_layout: fill
runtime: shiny
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
library(flexdashboard)
library(rmarkdown)
source('R/load_data.R')
```

```{r}
output$export_btn<- downloadHandler(
         filename = "report.html",
        content = function(file) {
        tempReport <- file.path(tempdir(), "test.Rmd")
        file.copy("test.Rmd", tempReport, overwrite = TRUE)
        out<-render(tempReport, html_document())
        file.rename(out,file)
     }
    )
```
````

Answer (score 0):

You are passing `file` to your function `content = function(file)`. `file` is a default R function. Did you mean to pass `filename` to the function instead?

```
output$export_btn<- downloadHandler(
         filename = "report.html",
        content = function(filename) {
        tempReport <- file.path(tempdir(), "test.Rmd")
        file.copy("test.Rmd", tempReport, overwrite = TRUE)
        out<-render(tempReport, html_document())
        file.rename(out,filename)
     }
    )
```

Comment: No, it doesn't matter, but when I don't source the `R/load_data.R` file, it's working fine ???

Comment: Not sure. But if it works when you aren't sourcing, maybe you are loading something that is in conflict?